# AWS Redshift - call multiple stored procedures in parallel

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

As a part of our current ETL flow which is primarily based on redshift, there are sequence of stored procedures which performs certain transformations and loads into the dimension and fact tables.

The thought process is to create one Master SP and call the individual child SP's to load the dimensions and facts, we are able to do this sequentially, however is there a way in which the child SP's can be executed in parallel from the master SP. While the dimension loading SP's can be executed in sequence, the thought process is to execute the fact loading SP's in parallel so that it will help in the overall process time.

Any thoughts / pointers would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of having parallel execution is to have multiple sessions (connections).  This will preclude the use of a single SP as the initiator of the child SPs.

Many ETL tools have the ability to initiate parallel connections to the database so this should be possible.  However, you need to aware of the coherency and data consistency implications of running ETL processes in parallel.  Is there an order in which the dimension tables need to be updated?  Will any ETL processes be using a table while another is updating it?   There is usually an order in which things need to happen and parallel execution cannot ensure that order.  That said you usually can find some parallelism to exploit, you just need to make sure that actions that need to be ordered are ordered through sequential execution.